# illegal start expression error when compiling code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

okay with some help i redid code, but when i try to comppile i keep getting an error. error: illegal start of expression (line 17)...the arrow points at the end of the joption code. I do not understand what it wants me to do.  Heres the code:

```
public class Project0 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char uppercase = 'E'; 
    char lowercase = 'e'; 
    int isLower=0; 
    int isUpper =0; 
    String inputWord; 

inputWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sentence"); 
    while (!inputWord.equals("stop")) 
        { 
        isLower = wordIsThere(inputWord, lowercase); 
        isUpper = wordIsThere(inputWord, uppercase); 

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("Number of " +inputWord+ " Lower: " +isLower+ "Upper: " +isUpper+)); 

      inputWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sentence or enter stop"); 
      isUpper=0;//reset 
      isLower=0; 
 }//while ends here. 

      System.out.println("ENDS"); 
  }//main 
     public static int wordIsThere(String findMe, char theLetter) 
  { 
    int count=0; 
   for (int i=0; i<findMe.length(); i++ ) 
     if (findMe.charAt(i) == theLetter) 
 count++; 
        return count; 
  }
      }
```

Comment: which is line number 17? There are 3 JOptionPane code there.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the last `+` operator from the `showMessageDialog` method

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
   (null, ("Number of " +inputWord+ " Lower: " +isLower+ "Upper: " +isUpper));
                                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `+` at the end of your string concatenation, so Java is expecting something else to be added.

```
//                                                              Here
("Number of " +inputWord+ " Lower: " +isLower+ "Upper: " +isUpper+)
```

Remove the `+` or add something else to the concatenation.